# weblogic server Test page for web service is different from wsdl

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have problem with weblogic server Test page for web service which is different from wsdl. If i run from Jdeveloper then i get textfileds which i can enter and press invoke at web there is just xml which is wrong. Why Weblogic create wring WS test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaking the capabilities of the JDeveloper IDE with basic web service definitions.

WSDL is an XML file, so when you deploy your WSDL on a target server, it will open up and show you the XML content. This is the same as opening the WSDL file in a browser directly.

JDeveloper as an IDE has additional tools that allow embedded testing of the web service, allowing you to pass parameters and see the output.

For testing your WSDL without JDeveloper, you need to write a client that will call the web service and get the results.